# Recyclerview items with checkbox gets distorted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have a `RecyclerView` with items and all of them have a `checkbox`. The point is that you can only set one `checkbox` as `checked` (something like favourite). Everything works fine until there are enough items that you need to scroll the `RecyclerView`. But, when there's enough items to scroll, then some of the item's names disappear and none of the `checkboxes` work except one and it is all stuck. Also, I get the following exception:

`"Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling"`

This is what I am doing:

```
holder.getBinder().cbIsFavourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (mListener == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (isChecked) {
                for (Peem peemTmp : mPeemList) {
                    if (peemTmp.isFavourite()) {
                        peemTmp.setFavourite(false);
                    }
                }
                peem.setFavourite(true);
                PeemAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                peem.setFavourite(false);
                removeFavouriteShops(peem);
            }

            mListener.onFavouriteChecked(peem);
        }
    });
```

The error occurs on this line `PeemAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`
If I remove that line it is all okay, but multiple `checkboxes` can be selected which is not the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use RadioButton and RadioGroup ?

Else try to call notifyDataSetChanged() in a post Runnable, it will be called after layout computing. Something like this:

```
myView.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
     });
```

**EDITED:**

```
holder.getBinder().cbIsFavourite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (mListener == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (isChecked) {
                for (Peem peemTmp : mPeemList) {
                    if (peemTmp.isFavourite()) {
                        peemTmp.setFavourite(false);
                    }
                }
                peem.setFavourite(true);
                holder.getBinder().cbIsFavourite.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   PeemAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
              });

            } else {
                peem.setFavourite(false);
                removeFavouriteShops(peem);
            }

            mListener.onFavouriteChecked(peem);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It was done this way so I can't implement radio buttons now. But how can I use your example in my case?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. The last 3 bottom items start to flicker and nothing is clickable. I've tried using `notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mPeemList.size());` and it works but there are sometimes problems with the first item...

Comment: Sure your OnCheckedChangeListener is called In recursion due when you change the checked state within the listener it's called again, you should change the basic design or use radiobuttons that already implement by themselves that only one option can be selected.

Comment: Hmm but how do I implement radio buttons in recyclerview where every item would have its own radio button?

Comment: RadioButtons don't need a RecyclerView, you use a RadioGroup with RadioButton child views inside. You can define an empty RadioGroup in the layout and then add or remove RadioButtons programatically using ViewGroup.addView or removeView.

Comment: But if the options are fixed and always the same you can directly define it in the layout xml